# Pagination Break

Tags: php, pagination

I need to break the pagination to show like this 123456....320
At present my pagination shows all the records from 1 to 320 following is the code that I use for pagination. I used for loop and if else statement to display all the pages but I am not getting where to enter the code to break in between.

```
### Pagination on All results ###
$mx_page = ceil($page_count/$ttl_rws_);
$nav_pg = '';
$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

for($page = 1; $page <= $mx_page; $page++){
    if($page == $page_no){
        $nav_pg .= '<li class="active"><a href="#">'.$page.'</a></li>';
    } else{
        if(isset($_GET['page'])){
            $self_ = preg_replace("/page=\d+/", "page=".$page, $self);
        } else {
            $self_ = $self.'&page='.$page;
        }
        $nav_pg .= '<li><a href="'.$self_.'">'.$page.'</a></li>';
    }
}
if ($page_no > 1){
    $page = $page_no - 1;
    if(isset($_GET['page'])){
            $prv_page = '<li><a href="'.preg_replace("/page=\d+/", "page=".$page, $self).'">&laquo;</a></li>';
            $frst_page = '<li><a href="'.preg_replace("/page=\d+/", "page=1", $self).'">Frist</a></li>';
    } else {
            $prv_page = '<li><a href="'.$self.'&page='.$page.'">&laquo;</a></li>';
            $frst_page = '<li><a href="'.$self.'&page=1'.'">Frist</a></li>';
        }
} else {
    $prv_page = '';
    $frst_page = '';
}
if ($page_no < $mx_page) {
    $page = $page_no + 1;
    if(isset($_GET['page'])){
        $nxt_page = '<li><a href="'.preg_replace("/page=\d+/", "page=".$page, $self).'">&raquo;</a></li>';
        $lst_page = '<li><a href="'.preg_replace("/page=\d+/", "page=".$mx_page, $self).'">Last</a></li>';
    } else {
        $nxt_page = '<li><a href="'.$self.'&page='.$page.'">&raquo;</a></li>';
        $lst_page = '<li><a href="'.$self.'&page='.$mx_page.'">Last</a></li>';
    }
} else {
    $nxt_page = '';
    $lst_page = '';
}
echo $frst_page.$prv_page.$nav_pg.$nxt_page.$lst_page;
```

Comment: Where do you set `$page_no`'s value?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it within the `for` loop:

```
$maxButtons = 10;
$threshold = 20;
$lastButtons = 3;
$dots = " ... ";

for($page = 1; $page <= $mx_page; $page++){
    if($page == $page_no){
        $nav_pg .= '<li class="active"><a href="#">'.$page.'</a></li>';
    } else{


        if(isset($_GET['page'])){
            $self_ = preg_replace("/page=\d+/", "page=".$page, $self);
        } else {
            $self_ = $self.'&page='.$page;
        }

        /*
         * this should give something like
         * 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ... 49 50
         * on 50 pages:
         * We have more than $threshold pages and we are behind
         * $maxButtons to show and we did not reach the $lastButtons value
         * so we only show some dots:
         */
        if ( $mx_page > $threshold && $page > $maxbuttons && 
                                         $page < ($mx_page - $lastButtons )
        {
            $nav_pg .= $dots;
            $dots = '';
        }
        else
            $nav_pg .= '<li><a href="'.$self_.'">'.$page.'</a></li>';
    }
}
```

This is not checked against the other logic but should give an indication on how to approach this problem.

Comment: If I keep ... in for loop then it is printing all ... ... ... until the last page and also it is navigable till the first 10 pages then it is not moving accordingly I mean if I am on page 34 it should show the last 1 2 3 4 ... 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 ... 300.

Comment: Ah yes, will make a fix!

Comment: But in this I am not getting the values in between 10 - to last. Now it shows only 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 123 124 125 126 and between 10 to 123 is not accessible.

Comment: If I would have to achieve in between links where I have to change the code?

Comment: Hey that's simple algorithm alley stuff, fiddle with the incrementors and the start and max values a bit.